# plugin/script for radare2 similar to mona for immunity debugger

Tags: radare2, exploit

I would like to use radare2 for windows exploit-development, however I could not find a way to emulate the functionality of using Immunity-Debugger + mona.py when checking for badchars. Is there a plugin/script that I am not aware of? Or is there a better way to do it in general?